# LoadError: Unable to load constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I have a module with a class that shares a name with a class from the ruby standard library. My class needs to call the class and I'm getting a LoadError.

```
require 'csv'

module Generator
  class CSV
    def generate_and_write
      ::CSV.open(filename) {
        # some functionality
      }
    end
  end
end
```

When I call `Generator::CSV.new.generate_and_write` I get a LoadError exception that states:

```
Unable to autoload constant Generator::CSV, expected /app/services/generator/csv.rb to define it (LoadError)
```

The exception is coming from:

```
vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:495:in 'load_missing_constant'
```

When debugging the app, a RunTime exception is thrown when loading the class:

::CSV = {RunTimeError} Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant CSV.

My `config/application.rb` has `config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'services', 'generator')` to ensure the service classes are auto loaded with the rest of the app.

How can I call to the standard library CSV class without conflicting with the name of my class?

Comment: Where did you place the above code?

Comment: @D-side This code is in a service class in `app/services/generator/csv.rb`. My `config/application.rb` is configured to autoload the generator directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by renaming the Generator module to FileGenerators. (I am sure FileGenerator would have worked as well but it makes more sense to have a plural module because it contains multiple FileGenerators.)

```
module FileGenerators
  class CSV < FileGenerators::Base
    def generate_and_write
      ::CSV.open {
        # ...
      }
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I believe current versions of rails autoload `app/**/*` so you shouldn't need to add anything to your autoload.

Second, the problem is that the Rails Inflector expects a file named csv.rb to define a class named `CSV` not `Csv`. If you rename your class to CSV, then it should load fine.

To call the base `CSV` inside of that class, use the scope operator `::CSV` to specify the top level `CSV` as opposed to `Generator::CSV`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately this does not resolve the issue.

I tried without modifying autoload_paths in the application.rb but none of the classes would initialize (NameError).

I renamed the class to CSV in the Generator module but the issue persists. I also added the scope operator in the #generate_and_write method but the issue persists.

Comment: Your edit changed the class as I was writing this. Is it CSV or Csv in the code? And are you calling `Generator::Csv.new.generate_and_write` or `Generator::CSV.new.generate_and_write` in the call

Comment: Sorry, hit enter too early on the initial comment. It is CSV in the code, and I've updated the examples to match. I am calling Generator::CSV.new.generate_and_write where the exception occurs.

Comment: Adding the scope operator results in the following RunTime error: "Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant CSV"